# Swift TableView Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

I am trying to create tableView cells and customize the layout. But it seems anything I add inside my cells get stuck being the same size height and width as the cell itself. How can I make it to where I can design my cells however I like? i.e, make my images a specific size with margins and paddings. Even my text height is being stretched out to the cells height. I added the borders so that it's visible for what I mean. The height of my label should be just the size of the text itself but it is still stretching.

I am stuck on tableview cells and want to design my cell layout fully programmatically without storyboarding. I've been trying to teach myself all day and just keep going in circles.

```
import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        
        let tableView = UITableView()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            self.tableView.delegate = self
            self.tableView.dataSource = self
            self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
        }
        
        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            tableView.frame = view.bounds
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 200
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 8
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Here is some text"
            cell.textLabel?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.textLabel?.layer.borderWidth = 5
            cell.textLabel?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "spiderman")!
            cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 5
            cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            return cell
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For that please remove func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 200
        }. from code. Its setting static height of Cell. Provide height in Storyboard to your cell components.

Comment: There is no cell in my storyboard. I did it all programmatically. Is that the only way? I have not touched the storyboard whatsoever.

Comment: So when you are programatically setting cell items please provide them height.

Comment: that also does not work, image and txt remains the same as cell height

Comment: even if I want to change the position of either my txt or image, nothing moves around

Comment: Diid you provided dynamic height to cell programatically.

Comment: yes sir I did. Still no change

Comment: Does your image have fixed height?

Comment: No it does not. I only add my image in the "cellForRowAt" and that is all. Like in the code posted.

Comment: You need to first provide static height to your image programatically.

Comment: can you also add constraints code here?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are using UITableViewCell's default textLabel

If you open a storyboard and play around with cell with 'basic' style, you will see that the text is always aligned to center.

I dont think you can adjust height or position of these two predefined properties (.textLabel and .imageView) directly.

Try to create imageView and label manually, and dont use cell.textLabel directly.

Example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    let label = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 0, width: 500, height: 50))
    label.text = "Here is some text"
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    label.layer.borderWidth = 5
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.addSubview(label)
    
    let image = UIImage(named: "spiderman")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5
    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.addSubview(imageView);
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay so I some how get what you're saying. and I tried what you wrote and it's a step forward. S would you suggest I use storyboard instead or is it possible fully programmatically.

Comment: it is possible to do it fully programmatically, if you see the source of storyboard they are doing similar thing just in different format. You still need to set constraints for this two views, so that they can work in different screen sizes. In storyboard you can just drag and drop and set these values. Personally I prefer to work in storyboard, but it is easy to cause git conflict when multiple developers work in same storyboard and raise separated pull requests.

Comment: okay I will try storyboarding. Rookie question. If I want to now do my tableviews in storyboard, how do I still make it work with the code I have now? Or do I need to totally reconstruct my code

Comment: 2 ways, 1 is to add UITableView as a View to your current UIViewController in storyboard, then link it to your tableView variable. ~~~~~~ Another way is to replace your UITableView in both class and storyboard. Second way requires a lot of change, but you can try, play around and to learn how it works.

Comment: better find an online tutorial on how to create a new tableView, because you would need to learn how to link datasource and delegate.

Comment: remember to give upvotes and mark accept this answer if you think the answer is ok =p

Comment: thank you so much for your help. You helped me big time and saved me from running in more circles